# add where condition in aggregate and group function in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have mongo model lets say *MYLIST* containing data like:-

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("542139f31284ad1461dbc15f"),
    "Category" : "CENTER",
    "Name" : "STAND",
    "Url" : "center/stand", 
    "Img" : [ { 
         "url" : "www.google.com/images", 
         "main" : "1", 
         "home" : "1", 
         "id" : "34faf230-43cf-11e4-8743-311ea2261289" 
    },
      { 
         "url" : "www.google.com/images1", 
         "main" : "1", 
         "home" : "0", 
         "id" : "34faf230-43cf-11e4-8743-311e66441289" 
    } ]
}
```

I execute the following query to the *MYLIST* collection:

```
db.MYLIST.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$Category", 
        "Name": { "$addToSet": { 
            "name": "$Name",
            "url": "$Url",
            "img": "$Img"
        }}
    }},
    { "$sort": { "_id" : 1 } }
]);
```

And I got the following result -

```
[ 
     {  _id: 'CENTER',
     Name: 
     [ { "name" : "Stand", 
          "url" : "center/stand", 
    "img":                                                                                                                 { "url" : "www.google.com/images" , "main" : "1", "home" : "1", "id" : "350356a0-43cf-11e4-8743-311ea2261289" } 
      }] 
     },
     {  _id: 'CENTER',
     Name: 
     [ { "name" : "Stand", 
          "url" : "center/stand", 
    "img":                                                                                                                 { "url" : "www.google.com/images1" , "main" : "1", "home" : "0", "id" : "34faf230-43cf-11e4-8743-311ea2261289" } 
      }] 
     }
    ]
```

As you can see my `img` key itself is an *array of objects*, Hence I am getting multiple entries for the same category of each entry in `img` array.

What I actually need is to get only those images that have some value for `home` key. 
expected result:-

```
[ 
     {  _id: 'CENTER',
     Name: 
     [ { "name" : "Stand", 
          "url" : "center/stand", 
    "img":                                                                                                                 { "url" : "www.google.com/images" , "main" : "1", "home" : "1", "id" : "350356a0-43cf-11e4-8743-311ea2261289" } 
      }] 
     },
    ]
```

Hence I would like to add where the condition for `img.home > 0` on the above-mentioned query, Could anybody help me to resolve this issue as my relatively new to MongoDB.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you actually trying to get the unique items grouped per category? Or are you just trying to get only the items in the array that  match `"home" = 1`? Perhaps show something of what you expect.

Comment: I want unique category.
and then in category itself I want to find unique name with their url and images.LIke this Structure: -[ 
  { _id: 'BRAKE',
    Name:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
   ] 
  },
  { _id: 'CENTER',
    Name:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
     ] },
]

Comment: You are not really explaining what `"home" = 1` has to do with this. Do you actually want to filter this? Or are you just trying to explain that you wan the "unique" items by "url" or something as well. You can edit your question and add details. [Object][Object] is not much of an explanation.

Comment: You could format that better, as well as you seem to be showing your "current" results. I'm asking you what you are "expecting" to see.

Comment: I think now you are able to understand what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still really not sure if this is what you want or even why you would be using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) on this grouping. But if all you want to do is "filter" the content of the array returned in your result, then what you want to do is [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the array elements to your condition after processing an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline in order to "de-normalize" the content:

```js
db.MYLIST.aggregate([
    // If you only want those matching array members it makes sense to match the 
    // documents that contain them first
    { "$match": { "Img.home": 1 } },

    // Unwind to de-normalize or "un-join" the documents
    { "$unwind": "$Img" },

    // Match again to "filter" out those elements that do not match
    { "$match": { "Img.home": 1 } },

    // Then do your grouping
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$Category", 
        "Name": { 
            "$addToSet": { 
                "name": "$Name",
                "url": "$Url",
                "img": "$Img"
            }
        }
    }},

    // Finally sort
    { "$sort": { "_id" : 1 } }
]);
```

So the `$match` pipeline is the equivalent of a general query or "where clause" in SQL terms, and can be used at any stage. It is usually best to have this as a first stage when there is some type of filtering that results from this. It reduces the overall load by reducing documents to be processed even if "all" of the end results are not removed as would be the case of working with an array.

The `$unwind` stage allows the array elements to be processed just like another document. And of course you can just use another `$match` pipeline stage after this in order to just match the documents to your query condition.

Comment: because I want unique combination of category and name.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.